# BSOD with many errors

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard, bsod, crash

Ok I am tired of this , I have tried all possible solution but nothing works. Now I think I need to post my case.  After many years of savings , I have finally built my favorite PC and everything was working perfectly. Here is my specs :

- Gigabyte Aorus b550 master
- AMD Ryzen 7 5800x
- 2X AORUS RGB Memory DDR4 16GB (2x8GB) 4400MHz  ( two identical kits with total of 32 GB)
- GIGABYTE OC RTX 3070

But after just one month of use , I have moved back with my chair and it has just touched the the head of the power strip cable that was inserted into the power socket and then suddenly the computer has restarted  (and the tv ) , I don't know how this has happened since it was expected that the pc should shutdown due to power loss. Since then , the computer start crashing with many BSOD errors but the majority was with MEMORY_MANAGMENT error and then I have done the following trials :
1 ) I have reinstalled the windows , however still some BSOD crashes has happened but with less frequency than before .
2) I have changed the SSD and still getting BSOD crashes with MEMORY_MANAGMENT error .
3) I have then tested my memory with Memtest 86 with 4 passes and 0 errors. Still I was getting BSOD crashes. Still I was getting BSOD crashes.
4) For making sure that the CPU and GPU are working fine , I have made a stress test for each of them and they have passed the tests. Still I was getting BSOD crashes.
5) I have then plugged in only 2 sticks at a time. The system was working fine and all the combinations have worked good with no BSOD crashes.
6) Now , I have again plugged in the 4 sticks and the system is working fine till now (  I will edit the post if any crashes happens ) , however , the memory speed is now 2666 Mhz although XMP is enabled instead of 4400 Mhz :( . Also the volt is 1.5V ( I don't have any idea about RAM voltages by the way , its just for your own information ).

Note : My Bios version is the latest version . Now I don't know what to do to fix back my RAM speed and I have no Idea what is going on with my PC right now and causing these issues.

Comment: Make sure your system is set to produce mini dumps (Advanced System Settings) and then get Nirsoft (nirsoft.net) Blue Screen View to see (in the minidump) what is causing the issue. Blue Screen View is a decent beginning tool for this.

Comment: @John It is the ntoskrnl.exe , however , I am not facing any crushes now after I have removed and plugged in again the 4 sticks but this at the cost of using 2666 Mhz only of memory speed !

Comment: It appears you have tracked down the main reason.

Comment: @John , Still I cant understand the cause and how to fix it .

Comment: @John Note that  before the incident the four sticks where working at their rated speed 4400 Mhz.

Comment: Quick process of elimination - test each stick individually in each slot. See if you can see a pattern for the speeds; stick failing, slot failing, all failing...

Comment: @Tetsujin  I will do so and update you.

Comment: @Tetsujin Done. There are no crashes , however , each stick works with a speed of 2671 Mhz with XMP enabled , instead of their rated speed.